# CSS Prevent Overflow when Using transform SCALE

Tags: html, css

i have a problem when using `transform: scale();`

basically, i'm using this scale on Image that has `overflow:hidden`

check this fiddle out for live action : https://jsfiddle.net/ns3vm3x6/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container1">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<p> i want this image to scale just like #example no. 2. how to achive this one? </p>
<br><br>
<div id="container2">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container1 {width:100%; height:200px; border:2px solid red;
 overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:no-wrap; }

#container2 {width:100%; height:200px; border:2px solid red; white- space:no-wrap;  }
img {width:200px; height:200px; transition:transform 1s linear; }
img:hover {transform:scale(2); }
```

How to prevent that overflow when scaling image?

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `position: absolute` for `img`

```
img {width:200px; 
height:200px; 
transition:transform 1s linear;
position: absolute; 
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns3vm3x6/7/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks jiiff for answering, well, i want the image no. 1 scaling like no. 2, not otherwise

Comment: I think I got it, give `position: absolute` to your `img` , is it what you want? @ChingChing [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns3vm3x6/7/)

Comment: wow that's really cool! but, what if i have a multiple images? just like this one https://jsfiddle.net/ns3vm3x6/8/ the image was hidden

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your container has the width and height as your desired outcome.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="bg agent-1"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

less (css)

```
    @keyframes fade-in {
      from {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      to {
        transform: scale(2);
      }
    }
    .agent-1 {
      animation: fade-in cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1) 10s forwards;
    }

    .bg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498811107811-a20a5be82dc1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&s=01f6b00c3415f756949a44aadb54567e);
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }

    .wrap {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/bavutanixu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer , I was also facing this issue but now its solved

Here I'm sharing

set images position to relative and set top: 20px;

```
img:hover {
       
     position: relative;
     top: 20px;

}
```